# SoundCloud Api - How to show playlists in favorites

Tags: soundcloud

is there any way to get sets (playlists) I marked as "like" from /users/userid/favorites ?

It seems that "/favorites" only shows tracks and no playlists? Maybe there is another way to check if a playlist was marked as "like", but I did not find anything usefull.
The SoundCloud-Android-App can handle this situation, but maybe it's not using the developer API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they use new API calls on `https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/`

favorite playlist are on `https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/users/UserId/playlist_likes`

Comment: Thank you for command, works like a charme.Is there a documentation for the new API? I'am thinking of the missing "repost" command.

Comment: still no documentation, in chrome, open dev tools (ctrl+shift+i), open network tab, head over soundcloud.com, and search what you need in the requests there. be aware that soundcloud reserve the rights to change these call endpoints at any time (e1 stands for experimental), not that they don't do that with old api.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get a complete list of sounds with an user-id, including sets and tracks with the experimental api? I dont want to query userid/tracks AND userid/playlists, would be nice to get this by one query (e.g. like this one: https://soundcloud.com/editors )

Comment: Wow, made a lucky shot by guessing...: /e1/users/userID/sounds --> that works for me

Comment: to get all likes, you can check this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27837649/1267015