# Soundcloud API - How to get all Favorite Sets?

Tags: soundcloud

Is there an official way of getting all Favorites including the favorite Sets of the user or getting all playlists including the favorite sets ?

i tried the following urls but none of them gets the job done:

```
/me/favorites/sets 
/me/sets
/me/playlists
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Just read through the documentation and it doesn't look like there is an official way of requesting this. You can get a list of favourite tracks - http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207/favorites.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID, but it seems to leave out the playlists for some reason. Sorry I couldn't answer your question, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait a bit, its part of their new API. 
Just change the user-id to yours.

https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/1672444/likes?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1